Dual boot menu no longer showing. No Ubuntu option in Boot Options
I have been operating a dual boot set up (Windows 10,Ubuntu 24.04) on my HP desktop for several months without any issues. However, this morning, when I came to boot my desktop, it automatically went to Windows, without showing a Boot Menu.
I tried to solve the issue by going into BIOS, Boot Menu and but I no longer see a Ubuntu option. I also made sure Windows FastStartup is turned off. I have legacy support enabled and secure boot disabled. Additionally, I checked my Windows update history and there were no updates ran in the last week.
Is there any way I can get Ubuntu back ?
I can no longer see the Ubuntu partition in my Disk Management...
Below is the Boot-Repair tool summary:
paste.ubuntu.com/p/NR25PQkHJg

HP's require you to change boot order in UEFI settings, not UEFI boot menu. And Windows updates may reset UEFI firmware changing to defaults (or Windows first and maybe UEFI Secure boot). And Windows updates may turn Windows fast startup back on or even bitlocker preventing grub from seeing Window to boot from grub menu.  If not UEFI settings post link: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report, do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer over Boot-Repair ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Yes, I checked the UEFI settings in HP. (F10) The boot order does not show Ubuntu like it used to. I also checked Windows update history, and there were no updates done in the past couple of days.

Here is the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report as requested:
paste.ubuntu.com/p/NR25PQkHJg

https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/dual-boot-menu-no-longer-showing-and-no-ubuntu-option-in-boot-options/51431 I posted the question on the forum above, where I was able to find an answer

Get a live install (eg, an ISO on burned to a flash drive), and boot from that.
Find your Ubuntu partition and mount it. Then, install the arch-install-scripts package onto the live environment, and and use the "arch-chroot" command (as root), like so:
sudo arch-chroot (your mountpoint here)
Be sure to replace (your mountpoint here) with the actual path to your mountpoint.
From there, you can run any command from your Ubuntu installation, which should get you up and running.
If you have a separate /boot partition, you can mount it like so: mount /boot. (If you have any other partitions that need mounting, mount them in the same way. Alternatively, you could run mount -a, which should mount everything automatically.) Next, run the install-grub command to reinstall the grub bootloader.
When you reboot, GRUB (the Grand Unified Bootloader) should now be restored, meaning you can now boot into Ubuntu.

See https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/dual-boot-menu-no-longer-showing-and-no-ubuntu-option-in-boot-options/51431
